# Insert date set with \date command

Tags: titles, datetime

I searched all morning to do this.

I want to insert in my custom title page the date, author, title set with the following commands

```
\date{The date}
\author{Me \and Other}
\title{the document title}
```

I want to insert those in my document anywhere (and my custom title page)

---

### Solution

```
\makeatletter
\@date
\@title
\makeatother
```

For the authors you put it in a tabular

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Does your title page already with these commands?

Comment: A default title pages contains that , but not a custom one with \begin{titlepage}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: 2nd answer is better

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not quite clear what exactly do you want to do. Usually the title is created by using `\maketitle` at the point of the document where you want to insert it. However it will be formatted whichever way your documentclass defines it. Redefining it is, of course, possible: you have to define `\@maketitle` appropriately, in which you can refer to `\@title`, etc.

However if you are not writing your own class, there might not be much of a point doing this. If you just want a title page, you don't have to use the `\title` etc commands, just put in the title whichever way you want. There is also a `\begin{titlepage}` - `\end{titlepage}` environment for creating a custom titlepage, but again, it does not use the `\title` command.

**EDIT:**

Yet another indirect option (along the lines of Andrea R's solution): define your own `\thedate`, `\thetitle`, etc commands using `\newcommand`, and then just use it in the titlepage:

```
\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}
\newcommand{\thetitle}{Your title}
...
\begin{titlepage}
   \centering\textbf{\thetitle}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: I'll try redefining maketitle like you say , what is the difference when there is a @ after the \

Comment: See http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=atsigns and http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ltxcmds

Answer (score 52):

### Implementation with `datetime`

If you are not using todays date, it is often wished to use the [package `datetime`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime?lang=en) which provides many features concerning dates and their formats:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdate{date}{06}{09}{2012}
\date{\displaydate{date}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
We discussed in the question session on \displaydate{date} unimportant stuff.
\end{document}
```

I hope the provided code helps people for their desired aim.

Answer (score 3):

I have been searching this today as well. Too bad now google points here. So I sucked it up ad partially resolved by doing:

```
\newcommand{\authorname}{Andrea Ratto}
\title{\authorname: Curriculum Vitae}
\author{\authorname}

... Curriculum vitae of \authorname ...
```

Does not work for dates using `\today` apparently.

Comment: This would work but i will try the way Aniko says, maybe mix it with yours

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `authoraftertitle` package to access title, author names and date.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authoraftertitle} % the definitions of \author, \title and \date can be accessed using \MyAuthor, \MyTitle and \MyDate;
\date{The date}
\author{Me and Other}
\title{the document title}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Date : \MyDate\\
Author : \MyAuthor\\
Title : \MyTitle
\end{document}
```

Output :

> Date : The date
> Author : Me and Other
> Title : the document title